# Password prompt when copying file to remote server using scp while password authentification disabled

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

I have remote server where i set up authentification through ssh keys. Where i try to connect to server by ssh user@hostname server didnt prompt me password but when i am trying to copy file from local machine to remote by following

```
scp -i /data/data/com.termux/files/home/pkgs_auto.lst user@IP: path_on_remote_server
```

Firstly i see following

```
Load key "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/pkgs_auto.lst": invalid format
```

Than server prompt me password although password disabled in sshd_config when i type password i see in shell

```
scp:. :not a regular file
```

What i am doing wrong

Comment: `scp -i` expects an identity file (= private key). Not sure what `pkgs_auto.lst` is, but it is not a private key.

Comment: Show us what you did. One transcript not chopped up.

Comment: 1. Does `scp` work without the opiton `-i`? 2. is the path after `-i` really to the key or is it the source file, that you want to transfer? 3. I don't think there should be a space after `user@IP:`

Comment: @AlexP pkgs_auto.lst is text file which contain all installed packages on my local machine

Comment: @sudodus i tried scp command without space after user@ip: and it worked. Thank you man

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: @sudodus if you write answer on my question as i can mark it by decision i will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a dialogue (comments) the problem was solved,

- The option `-i` was removed
- The space character after `user@ip:` was removed so that it was connected to the path on the server.